# How do bit masks work in Python?

Tags: python

Hi I wrote a program to see if a bit is "on" in class, but I'm not quite sure what it means by "on" and "off", and how bit masks work.

Here's the code:

```
def check_bit4(input):
    mask = 0b1000
    checker = input & mask
    if checker > 0:
        return("on")
    else:
        return("off")
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: Thanks! That link really helped!

Answer (score 5):

Computers represent integers with bits.  This is a binary representation of a number (that is, using base 2).  The only numbers in binary are 0 and 1, or "off" and "on".  If you are not familiar with binary, you should read up on it, but basically you count in binary like this:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
```

and so on... each column can be represented by `2^n` starting with 0. So the number `0101 = 2^3*0+2^2*1+2^1*0+2^0*1 = 5`.  Now when you "bit mask" something, you are basically just looking at the bits of value to you.  In your case, you are only looking at the "`2^3`" bit.  This is easily done by simply multiplying each bit with the corresponding bit in the mask. This can be useful for a lot of things.  Sometimes we assign meaning to each bit and telling whether it is on or off is very important.

In your example. If we passed in 13, this would happen:

```
13 means 1101 in computer speak
1101 mask with 1000.  Work on each bit individually:
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 0 = 0
0 * 0 = 0
1 * 0 = 0
checker = 1000 which means 8.
8 > 0 so return on.
```

An example returning false with 5:

```
5 means 0101 in computer speak
0101 mask with 1000.  Work on each bit individually:
0 * 1 = 0
1 * 0 = 0
0 * 0 = 0
1 * 0 = 0
checker = 0000 which means 0.
0 is not > 0 so return off.
```

Hope this helps.  You should be able to find extensive information about this stuff on the google machine.

Comment: TFW you notice that AND is no different than a multiplication without carry.